# How to format specific lines as bold within a paragraph in Outlook using PyAutoGUI?

Tags: python, automation, outlook, pyautogui, office-automation

I am trying to automate the process of writing an email in Outlook using PyAutoGUI. I need to write a paragraph in the email, with certain lines of text formatted as bold. However, I am having trouble getting PyAutoGUI to format specific lines as bold.

Here's an example of the paragraph I want to write:

Dear [Recipient],

I hope this email finds you well. I wanted to let you know that we have some exciting news to share. We recently launched a new product that has received a lot of positive feedback from our customers. **The product is designed to help people [feature 1] and [feature 2]**. We believe it has the potential to make a real difference in people's lives.

****Please let me know if you have any questions or would like to learn more.**
**
Best regards,

[Your Name]

I have tried using the pyautogui.hotkey() function to simulate the keyboard shortcut for bold formatting, then using the pyautogui.typewrite() function to type out the entire paragraph with the desired lines in bold. However, this approach does not seem to work with Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

You can automate Outlook from your Python code using the `win32com` package where you can set up the message body in the way you need. For example, take a look at the [automating Outlook](https://github.com/Hridai/Automating_Outlook) repo.

The Outlook object model supports three main ways of customizing the message body:

1. The [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-body-property-outlook) property returns or sets a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. The [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-htmlbody-property-outlook) property of the `MailItem` class returns or sets a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. Setting the `HTMLBody` property will always update the `Body` property immediately.
3. The Word object model can be used for dealing with message bodies. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) for more information.